# How to get ARN value for AWS alarm in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform to create an AWS alarm below,

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "terraform-product-monitoring-dynamoDB-UserErrors" {
  alarm_name                = "terraform-product-monitoring-dynamoDB-UserErrors"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "2"
  metric_name               = "UserErrors"
  namespace                 = "AWS/DynamoDB"
  period                    = "120"
  statistic                 = "Sum"
  threshold                 = "1"
  alarm_description         = "This metric monitors the UserErrors for DynamoDB"
  alarm_actions             = ["${module.admin_sns_email_topic.arn}"]
  insufficient_data_actions = []
}
```

I want to get the arn for the alarm, but

```
"${aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.terraform-product-monitoring-dynamoDB-UserErrors.arn}"
```

gives the error

```
Resource 'aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.terraform-product-monitoring-dynamoDB-UserErrors' does not have attribute 'arn' for variable 'aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.terraform-product-monitoring-dynamoDB-UserErrors.arn'
```

Any idea?

Cheers

Hammer

Answer (score 2):

Not all resources have `ARN`. If you need get the name of resource `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm`, use `id`

Reference:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_metric_alarm.html#id